# Getting the first Energy Sphere in Level 2-2

Tags: kirby-return-to-dreamland

In Kirby's Return to Dreamland, in level 2-2, to get what I think is the first Energy Sphere in the level (it's the first one I have found) you need to use the Stone Ability on a switch, which looks like it removes the upside-down U shaped wall that is in your way. However, that wall gets replaced with a different wall soon after the first one disappears. I can't seem to get Kirby to run fast enough to get to the Sphere in time.

Is there a trick to this that I am just not getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, no trick. You're just a bit too slow. :P That said though, notice how the appearing wall's a bit funny-shaped - you have a bit more time to stick yourself in the top-left corner of the right-hand area before the wall gets there, as opposed to trying to run and jump right at the sphere.

If that still doesn't work for you, try dragging Hammer into the stage; there'll be more time for you to move after whacking the stake.